Use another data as field in group-relationship
I ask myself on how to do the following thing :
Each user in the system has an avatar (media field in user account).
I use the group module to build "organizations". Each organization has members. When a user is added to an organization, the admin has the choice to add or not an "avatar" to the added member. The avatar field is in the relationship.
The goal is the following :
If an avatar is set to the relationship, use it ;
If not, use the standard avatar from the user profile ;
I implemented a custom module with hook_preprocess_group_relationship and check for the current relationship if the relation contains avatar or not, and if it's not the case, I would like to attach to the "content" array the avatar from the user profile. But I don't see how to do that...
Actually I use the following code :
    if (!isset($variables['content']['field_avatar']['#theme'])) {
      $user = $gr->getEntity();
      $medias = $user->get('field_user_avatar')->referencedEntities();
      if (count($medias)) {
        $media = $medias[0];
        $render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('media')->view($media, 'default');
        $variables['content']['field_avatar'] = $render;
      }
    }


The original field_avatar content is a "theme field", but the one I put as replacement is a media, so it doesn't display it.
An idea on how to manage the replacement to mimic the same use ?
Thanks in advance.

Ok... Five minutes ago I found this thread : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240002/how-to-apply-a-field-formatter-to-a-node-field-programmatically
And it work for my case :
    if (!isset($variables['content']['field_avatar']['#theme'])) {
      $user = $gr->getEntity();
      $medias = $user->get('field_user_avatar')->referencedEntities();
      if (count($medias)) {
        $view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('user')->viewField($user->get('field_user_avatar'), 'default');
        $variables['content']['field_avatar'] = $view;
      }
    }

